# Why the response speed SNMP in window Server 2008 is so slow when disable internet card

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

In VC++, i call method: SnmpMgrRequest(...) to get data from other PC, but when i disable internet connection. I tried to run this method in 2 different windows (windowXP and Window Server2008)

- Only take 1 second in Window XP to response error data.
- But take 7 seconds in Window Server 2008 to response error data.

Does anyone know why there is different about response speed in WindowXP and Window Server 2008?

Thank you.